# xampp--apache app fails to start

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am new to php. please help me out. i have a xampp installed on my windows. when i am trying to start apache service it throws me the error. Tried to track the error in apache error log which says "www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name" and on the control panel i get red lines

Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method

I searched over the internet and found over lot of solution but none of them worked for me.
i am using windows 7 - 64bit

Comment: Check that the port 80 and 443 aren't blocked!

Comment: With what was said above, make sure Skype is not running. That is using the application that causes the problem.

Comment: make sure you haven't installed xamp or wamp or such programs before , or fully uninstall it install again , and remove programs like skype ( as comment above said ) , some of them blocks some port

Comment: I don't have Skype/Wamp installed on my system